# Can i append array into string using bash?

Tags: arrays, bash

i would like to append each array element into this string,

```
arr=(col1 col2 col3)
str="to/path/${arr[@]}
```

output would be like this

```
to/path/col1
to/path/col2
to/path/col3
```

do you have any idea how?

Comment: `printf 'to/path/%s\n' "${arr[@]}"` will emit your desired output, while handling the array *as an array* the whole time, rather than trying to convert it to a string.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem

Answer (score 4):

Using bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
arr=(col1 col2 col3)
str=${arr[@]/#/\/path\/to\/}
echo "$str"
```

```
/path/to/col1 /path/to/col2 /path/to/col3
```

---

As Charles indicates, we're converting from an array to a string, which has negative consequences if you want to iterate over the result. In that case, try this:

```
arr=( "col 1" "col 2" "col 3" )
newarr=()
for elem in "${arr[@]}"; do
    newarr+=( "/path/to/$elem" )
done
printf "%s\n" "${newarr[@]}"
```

Comment: Huh. `arr2=( "${arr[@]/#//path/to/}" )` -- without the backslash escaping --
 seems to be what works in generating a new array with each element prefixed; I'll admit to being a bit surprised.